# How does other devices on my network receive incoming connections when I set public IP address to a specific device?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

So I set my router to assign the public IP to my laptop. And this opens up all ports to my laptop so that when I host a website or a minecraft server and so on, I don't have to forward my ports.
And now I'm wondering, what happens to all the other devices on the network? If all ports are forwarded to me, how do the other devices access internet and use applications like skype or play multiplayer games?

Comment: what is your exact model of router, and what is the specific name of the feature you enabled to do this? It sounds like you have created a DMZ host. DMZs are a kind of virtual network residing kind of outside your NAT wall. So, a host in the DMZ will not use NAT (at least not fully) to connect in and out, but non-DMZ hosts on the router will still use NAT to connect outside your LAN. The router will track the natted connections, so it can tell the differance between a non-natted request for a service off your laptop from a natted response to a phone requesting a webpage.

Comment: All your traffic is being forwarded to a single. Devices can send out but not recieve data on those ports.  Since your using DMZ that would be all of them

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between incoming and outgoing connections.  The "direction" of a connection is the direction of the initial packet in that connection -- replies to that connection are considered part of the same connection, not a different one.

For outgoing, the router knows that the connection was initiated by a particular internal computer, and it routes the reply portions of that connection back to the originator.

For incoming, you've set your router to forward each connection to your internal computer.  The router also knows about these connections and sends the replies back where they came from.